# × NotSupportedError: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': the name "mgt-mock-provider" has already been used with this registry

Tags: microsoft-graph-toolkit

> Graph toolkit ×
> NotSupportedError: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': the name "mgt-mock-provider" has already been used with this registry
> using these version
> "@microsoft/mgt": "^2.3.0",
> "@microsoft/mgt-react": "^2.3.0",

tried to upgrade and down grade

Answer (score 1):

```
"@microsoft/mgt": "^2.3.0", 
"@microsoft/mgt-react": "^2.3.0"
```

Both contain the same code but are scaffolded for different environments. Please only use one reference at a time, if your project is react, use **only** the `mgt-react` library.

Comment: Nic Vogt- i am using the toolkit components to create a library using(create-react-library), and the main app which use library also has some toolkit components, when ever i link the library to the main app there is problem with the same : "error Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': the name "mgt-mock-provider".

The library and the main app work independently they render the graph toolkit components , there is a problem when I do npm link and link to main app,

Comment: I found differences between the packages and posted the question https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/issues/1513